# Tkinter tkFileDialog module- limited to one folder

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter, directory

The python Tkinter module `filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir , title, filetypes)` works fine and opens the initial directory in a new Tkinter window.
But, I can move freely between folders and directories in the new Tkinter window and open files from every directory I want although I defined an initial directory.

I would like to know if I can define an initial directory and the user can open files from this specific directory without moving freely between non-defined directories.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use,  initialdir:

```
dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes, initialdir=r"C:\Users\danil\Documents")
```